# Subdirectory site links loading main directory pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I am running an ecommence site on Opencart ver 1.5.6.4 and am not at the level as most people on this site.

I have my live site running from the root directory. I have set up a subdirectory called "oc2" and copied my site from the root to the subdirectory.  I am doing this to do some testing on a new template before transferring it onto the production site. Most things appear to be OK, but there are a few links that still point back to the main site pages, not the pages in the subdirectory. My question is, what am I doing wrong in my .htaccess or config files that would cause this?

As an example, the link to the blog in both the main site as well as the subdirectory is as follows:

/index.php?route=bossblog/bossblog

In the subdirectory I would expect this to load the page: www.example.com/oc2/index.php?route=bossblog/bossblog, but instead it loads www.example.com/index.php?route=bossblog/bossblog

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /oc2/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

My config file in the /oc2 directory is:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/oc2/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.example.com/oc2/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.example.com/oc2/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/oc2/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.example.com/oc2/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'pump1080_xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Pumpxxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'pump1080_xxx');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

My config file in the /oc2/admin directory is:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example.com/oc2/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.example.com/oc2/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.example.com/oc2/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example.com/oc2/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.example.com/oc2/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.example.com/oc2/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/pump1080/public_html/oc2/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'pump1080_xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Pumpxxx');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'pump1080_xxx');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

Any thoughts of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you....

Comment: /means start from root, so that's why the link ignores the subdirectory. i would of thought for the purpose of testing a template you could just manually work around this - if not a subdomain is a much better idea than a subdirectory

Comment: @rtfm - Thank you for the suggestion.  That worked.